# В чем отличие Web Site от Web Application?

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование

Я правильно понимаю, что проект сайта сейчас не актуален и лучше использовать Web App?

Comment: В том что Web-Site содержит обработчик, который "на ходу" собирает из cs dll-ки (компилирует), а потом "запускает" страницу (публикуется и aspx и cs), а application - там весь проэкт собирается в dll, и на все страницы подвязывается одна dll (публикуются aspx и dll).

Comment: @nick_n_a, т.е профит в том, что я могу на ходу редактировать страницы в проекте Сайта, в том время, как в App я должен перекомпилировать отдельные страницы и подсовывать Dll в работающий сайт?

Comment: C app веселее, там есть папка release в которую идут "обработанные" aspx с привязкой к конкретной dll (в хвосте dll компилятор записывает версию). Нужно опубликовать всю папку release  (возможно сейчас этот процесс чуть упростили, в 2005 так). Насчёт переименовать dll не уверен. А WebSite проще редактировать, зато сложнее с "версионностью".

Comment: @nick_n_a, а сайт придется целиком перекомпилировать или можно "заменить колесо" на ходу подсунув новые dll?

Comment: По моему как-то можно подсунуть новую dll. Есть правда ещё одна "лажа" aspx всёравно компилируются в dll но другие чем cs. Но это делается полностью автоматом. У меня редко получается редактировать сайт изменяя лишь dll (cs-ки), aspx то же менять приходится.

Comment: Вообщем моё мнение, если сайт небольшой, там до 10 - 20 страниц, то WebSite удобнее. А если это большой портал, где нужна версионность, возможность откатится к другой версии, то лучше app и какая-то примочка для развёртывания и свёртывания. У студии есть плагин который cab-архив  делает.

Comment: @nick_n_a, оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WebSite** Преимуществом беспроектной разработки является то, что она представляет собой простой и прямолинейный процесс. В случае создания беспроектного Web-сайта не требуется развёртывать никаких лишних вспомогательных файлов. Вместо этого каждый находящийся в папке Web-сайта файл автоматически считается частью Web-приложения. (Такая модель имеет смысл потому, что каждая Web-страница в виртуальном каталоге доступна по отдельности независимо от того, считает её разработчик официальной частью своего проекта или нет).

Беспроектная разработка продолжает пользоваться популярностью по перечисленным ниже причинам:

- Упрощает сам процесс разработки. Требуется просто скопировать все файлы из каталога Web-сайта на Web-сервер: нет никаких ни проектных, ни отладочных файлов, которых следовало бы избегать.
- Упрощает управление файлами. При желании удалить страницу можно просто удалить ассоциируемые с ней файлы. При желании добавить новую страницу или перенести какую-нибудь страницу из одного Web-сайта в другой, необходимо лишь скопировать ассоциируемые с нею файлы: ни иметь дело с Visual Studio, ни редактировать файл проекта не требуется. Из-за отсутствия файла проекта, о котором нужно было бы заботиться, в Web-страницы даже авторские коррективы можно вносить другими средствами.
- Упрощает совместную командную работу. Разные люди могут по отдельности работать над разными Web-страницами, и блокировать никакие проектные файлы при этом не требуется (не путать с SVN).
- Упрощает <del>отладку</del> обновление/доработку. В случае WebApplication при изменении даже одной единственной страницы заново необходимо компилировать всё приложение. В случае WebSite разработки каждая страница компилируется отдельно, причём только тогда, когда запрашивается впервые.
- Упрощает смешивание языков, Поскольку каждая Web-страница компилируется отдельно, разработчик волен писать код для своих страниц на разных языках. В случае WebApplication разработки, ему для этого придётся создавать либо отельные Web-проекты (что усложнит управление), либо отдельные проекты библиотеки классов.
- *минус* усложняется версионность, если проэкт собран из нескольких, то могут возникнуть сложности сделать откат на предыдущую версию (если нету копии всего проекта).
- *минус* при обновлении общей библиотеки если функционально затронуты другие страницы - они могут посыпаться exception-ами. При использовании SVN может понадобится массово менять файлы. У меня уходил целый рабочий день что б такой проэкт заставить работать в студии (на IIS работает в студии не сразу).

---

**WebApplication**  При создании Web-проекта Visual Studio генерирует ряд дополнительных файлов, включая пользовательские файлы проекта с расширением .csproj, а также файл решения с расширением .sln. При компоновке приложения Visual Studio генерирует временные файлы, которые размещает в подкаталоге obj, и один или более .pdb-файлов с отладочными символами, которые размещает в подкаталоге bin. Ни один из этих файлов не должен развёртываться на Web-сервере, когда Web-приложение будет готово. Более того, также не должны развёртываться и файлы исходного кода на C# (файлы с расширением .cs), поскольку Visual Studio предварительно компилирует их в DLL-сборку. Публиковать нужно то что в папке *Release*, или есть утилиты (например Deployment project который делает CAB, MSBuild) которые упрощают разворачивание проэкта.

К числу наиболее важных преимуществ Web-проектов относятся перечисленные ниже:

- Система проектной разработки является более чёткой, чем система беспроектной разработки. Всё дело в том, что в файле проекта явно перечисляются все файлы, которые должны входить в этот проект. Это позволяет перехватывать вероятные ошибки (вроде недостающих файлов) и даже анализировать возможные варианты атак (вроде добавления злонамеренным пользователем нежелательных файлов).
- Web-проекты предусматривают больше возможностей для управления файлами. Одним из примеров может служить случай, когда создаётся несколько проектов, и все они размещаются в подкаталогах внутри одного и тоже же виртуального каталога. В таком сценарии получается, что файлы хранятся отдельно для целей разработки, но при этом по сути всё равно являются частью одного и того же приложения для развёртывания. В случае беспроектной разработки возможности размещать файлы отдельно в таких подкаталогах не существует.
- Web-проекты предусматривают возможность настройки процесса развёртывания. Файлы проектов Visual Studio работают с утилитой MSBuild, которая позволяет настраивать и автоматизировать процесс компиляции проекта, а также управлять генерируемой для Web-приложения сборкой, присваивая ей подходящее имя, добавляя в неё подпись и т.д.
- Web-проекты работают лучше в некоторых сценариях миграции. По этой причине ASP.NET автоматически преобразовывает Web-проекты Visual Studio .NET 2003 в Web-проекты Visual Studio 2008. Это преобразование требует внесения в страницы меньшего количества изменений.

  Трудности с которыми я сталкивался - в папку Release генерируется DLL с разными именами, а aspх привязаны к конкретной сборки. Приходится или переименовывать dll или менять aspx (думаю это где-то отключается). Процесс обновления страницы чуть сложнее. WebApplication или WebSite указывается в заголовке aspx файла (т.е. теоретически можно смешивать, но как правило так не делают).

Источник http://skillcoding.com/Default.aspx?id=98